# How to run refresh all queries in Access, but do it from Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I found an easy way to list all queries in Access, from within Access.

```
Set dB = Application.CurrentData
For Each qry In db.AllQueries
Debug.Print qry.Name
Next qry

strMsg = " -- Queries listing complete -- "

Procedure_Done:
dmwListAllQueries = strMsg
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
strMsg = Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume Procedure_Done
```

What I really want to do is refresh all select queries in Access, but I want to do this from within Excel.  I'm running other processes in Access, from within Excel, and I want to try to control everything from within my Excel environment, rather than switching back and forth between Excel and Access.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Refreshing a query sounds weird, unless you want to change its code. I guess you want to refresh the recordset populated by the query? Then you can create an Access.Application object and assign it to your Access-DB and use it in Excel-VBA just like you can use Excel objects in Access-VBA. You just need to set the right references in VBA-Editor (depending on your needs). E.g. you can create a recordset from the query as usual (`Set rs = db.Openrecordset`) you just need to set db as the external Access-DB instead of `CurrentDb`.

Comment: Ok.  How do I do that?

Comment: I found your question [Trying to Run Make Table Query in Access, from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555102/trying-to-run-make-table-query-in-access-from-excel) and that's the trick to get the `db` object that is equal to `Set db = CurrentDb`, You just get bitten by a faulty parameter query. Use `MyDatabase.Execute myQryStr, dbFailOnError` to test your approach. You are familiar with `add watch` in vba-code (in Debug-tab, make `Watch Window` visible  in  View tab.)? With a watch  and breakpoint(s) it is easier to debug.